# Mocked Instance is always Null

Tags: java, mockito

Sample Code :
File : InfoRequestControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InfoRequestControllerTest {

InfoRequestController InfoRequestControllerTest;

@Mock
Service service;

@Mock
UserInfo info

@Before
public void setupMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        InfoRequestControllerTest = new InfoRequestController(argmock1, argmock2, argmock3);

}

@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void InfoTest() {
    when(service.getInfo(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt(), anyString()).thenReturn(info);
    RespDto respDto = InfoRequestControllerTest.InfoRequest("string", "string", "string").call();

}
```

File : InfoRequestController.java

```
public Callable<UserInfo> InfoRequest() 
{
  ...
  UserInfo info = service.getInfo("string", "string" , int, int, null);
  ...
}
```

So inside this InfoRequest method, I am always getting "info" as null.
I have added "@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)" at the beginning of InfoRequestControllerTest class. ALso "MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)" is present inside setup class.

I am not understanding inspite of mocking "info", why it's coming Null during the execution of test case.
Any pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working when I changed arguments in mocked function call from anyString(), anyInt() to any() i.e
Instead of

```
when(service.getInfo(anyString(), anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt()).thenReturn(info);
```

replaced this with :

```
when(service.getInfo(any(), any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(info);
```

Also I am avoiding passing of Null argument as I realized its not required as that variable would be always Null

Answer (score 1):

I dont know with what arguments you actually do the call `UserInfo info = service.getInfo("string", "string" , int, int, null);`
But in your test you stub the method for 2 strings, 2 Integers, and 1 String.
In your class it lookslike your last argument is NULL. So your stub doesn't match with the actual arguments used. so mockito will throw a `PotentialStubbingProblem` telling you your stub doesn't match with the actual method called. This can be fixed by adjusting you last parameter for your stub to for example 'any()' or `isNull()` or `nullable(String.class)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was sending it as Null because in the actual method that argument is passed as Null. Anyways, I had also tried any(), anyString() and the parameters you suggested as well. But no luck !!! The error which I keep getting is :  "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "package.info.someMethod" because "info" is null"

Comment: Cloud you share more of your code from `InfoRequestController` ? where do you initialize the `service`? In your constructor? Looking at your test code, you inject argmock1 as argument but what is argmock1?

Comment: I am not sure why taking this approach working for me. But thanks for all the help